# SQL direct query result set modification

Tags: query

I am using below code to fetch data from db.

```
$w = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read'); 
$table = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('mymodule/mymodule');

$result = $w->select()
    ->from($table)
    ->where('t_store in(0,?)', Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId());

$row = $w->fetchAll($result);
```

It is giving me an array of array something like below

```
Array
(
    [t_id] => 4
    [t_store] => 0
    [t_name] => name1
    [t_text] => text1
)
Array
(
    [t_id] => 6
    [t_store] => 0
    [t_name] => name2
    [t_text] => text2
)
```

But I wanted to have only t_text in my result set something like below

```
Array
(
    [t_text] => text1
)
Array
(
    [t_text] => text2
)
```

How can I modify my code or query to have above result set?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: try `$w->select('t_text')`.

Comment: @programmer_rkt Tried, it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code worked for me.

```
$result = $w->select()
    ->from($table, 't_text')
    ->where('t_store in(0,?)', Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId());
```

Answer (score 2):

Try it with:

```
$result = $w->select()
    ->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)
    ->columns('t_text')
    ->from($table)
    ->where('t_store in(0,?)', Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId());
```

Comment: Sorry, it is not working.

Comment: @AnshuMishra. I've edited the answer. Give it a try now.

Comment: Still not working.